# Ionic 2 passing tabs NavParams to tab

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm starting out on creating my first app using Ionic 2 and through a lot of trial and error have got to a point where no number of Google searching can find anything to help.

I'm trying to pass some NavParams to a tab. The NavParams are available in the parent tabs page:

```js
@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/tabs/tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  constructor(params: NavParams) {

      this.params = params;
      console.log(this.params); // returns NavParams {data: Object}

      // this tells the tabs component which Pages should be each tab's root Page
      this.tab1Root = Tab1;
      this.tab2Root = Tab2;
      this.tab3Root = Tab3;
    }
}
```

But I cannot seem to get the NavParams within a tab itself:

```js
@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/tab1/tab1.html'
})
export class Tab1 {
    constructor(nav: NavController, params: NavParams, platform: Platform) {
        this.nav = nav;
        this.params = params;
        this.platform = platform;

        console.log(this.params); // returns NavParams {data: null}
    }
}
```

I'm just not entirely sure how to pass the params from the tabs page to the tab itself or somehow request a param from the tab parent. I assume something like:

```js
this.tab1Root = Tab1(this.params);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This question is a few weeks old so you may have already found the answer. This feature was added in February: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5475.

Taking the code from your original tab page, let's say a parameter is passed to the "parent" tab page and we want to store it in a property called `fooId` (this could be an object, or just a simple integer or string value, whatever):

```js
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  constructor(params: NavParams) {

      this.params = params;
      console.log(this.params); // returns NavParams {data: Object}
      this.fooId = this.params.data;

      // this tells the tabs component which Pages should be each tab's root Page
      this.tab1Root = Tab1;
      this.tab2Root = Tab2;
      this.tab3Root = Tab3;
    }
}
```

Then in your tabs.html, you can reference it like this using the `rootParams` attribute (rootParams is referenced in the [documenation here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/tabs/Tab/)):

```html
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab tabTitle="Tab1" [root]="tab1Root" [rootParams]="fooId"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabTitle="Tab2" [root]="tab2Root" [rootParams]="fooId"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabTitle="Tab3" [root]="tab3Root" [rootParams]="fooId"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Then in your Tab1 page, you can reference your NavParams just like any other page and the value passed for `foodId` will be there.

Comment: This only works if the constructor is fired when loading the page. It does not work when updating it from Events.

Comment: I've created a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354553/ionic-2-update-routeparams-tabs

Answer (score 12):

For those who haven't figured out yet .....

I've searched a lot and the **only answer I got was using native storage or using a service or session storage**...but that wasn't what I wanted ...
So, **If you have data in NavParams** in Tabs.ts page and want to it **pass as [rootParam] to respective Tabs**...
then what you need to do is **instead of assigning NavParams to a variable** in Tabs.ts page what you can do is **bind it directly to the [rootParams]** in the HTML page.
Like ..

**tabs.ts**

```
constructor(public navParams: NavParams) { }
```

**tabs.html**

```
<ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" [rootParams]="navParams.get('single')" tabTitle="Customer"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" [rootParams]="navParams.get('second')" tabTitle="Map"></ion-tab>
```

**Or**

**tabs.html**

```
 <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" [rootParams]="navParams.data" tabTitle="Customer"></ion-tab>
```

**tab1.ts**

```
constructor( public navParams: NavParams) {}

ionViewDidLoad() {
  console.log('ionViewDidLoad tab1Page');
  console.log(this.navParams.data);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no direct way to pass Params in Tab-Pages that I know of.

I think you could play around with the *NavController* to make it work.

A neat workaround is to put the parameter into an injected service:
*app/services/params.js:*

```js
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class Params{
    constructor(){
        console.log("Params()");  
        this.params={};
    }
}
```

and in the controller:

```js
    import {Params} from '../../services/params'

    @Page({
      templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html',
    })
    export class XYPage{

    constructor(nav: NavController,platform: Platform, params: Params) {
       console.log("XYPage()",this);
       console.log("XYPage()", params.params);
       params.params={id="001"};
```

dont forget to inject the service in your @App

Comment: This works but I need to update the params. When a page updates data, the root page is listening for changes and it needs updates this.

Comment: I've created a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354553/ionic-2-update-routeparams-tabs

Comment: thats neat, and work for any ion-nav, not only this tab case

Answer (score 1):

I tried with many methods but none of them were helpful to me. As my application did not involve much of complexities, I implemented it using ionic native storage [plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage/). In the event that triggers the new tab page, I will store some variable in native storage(snippet is as below).

```
this.nativeStorage.setItem('myitem', {property: 'value', anotherProperty: 'anotherValue'})
  .then(
    () => console.log('Stored item!'),
    error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
  );
```

In the constructor or ionviewdidload page of the next tab page I will check for this variable and perform the required actions.Snippet is as below.

```
this.nativeStorage.getItem('myitem')
  .then(
    data => console.log(data),
    error => console.error(error)
  );
```

**Note:** This is suitable only for small application or where there is a requirement of passing limited set of variables. If there are lots of variable, it may take more space in the apps cache which may reduce the app performance.

Answer (score 1):

tabs.html - add **[rootParams]="paramName";** to the tab you want to pass data to

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab tabTitle="Tab1" [root]="tab1Root" [rootParams]="fooId"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabTitle="Tab2" [root]="tab2Root"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabTitle="Tab3" [root]="tab3Root"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

tabs.ts - set the **key and data**

```
export class TabsPage {
  this.tab1Root = Tab1;
  this.tab2Root = Tab2;
  this.tab3Root = Tab3;

  fooId: {
    firstName: "lawlesscreation",
    email: "user@email.com",
    score: number // can also set it later in the constructor
  }

  constructor() {
    let score = getScore(); //some method to get score
    this.fooId.score = score;
  }
}
```

tab1 page - import **NavParams** and use **this.navParams.get(key)** to get data

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html',
})
export class Tab1 {
  firstName = this.navParams.get('firstName');
  score = this.navParams.get('score');
  userEmail = this.navParams.get('email');

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

}
```

Comment: Please not just answer with source code, but explain your solution!