# Ionic 2 Passing async data from parent to child tabs

Tags: asynchronous, ionic-framework, tabs, ionic2

Referring to [Ionic 2 passing tabs NavParams to tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162308/ionic-2-passing-tabs-navparams-to-tab/37543598?noredirect=1#comment62576039_37543598)

The solution provided works. But what if the parameter is obtained by an async method in the parent? The first tab will never gets the value of "foodId".
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35176544/1016128) in the question you linked is a good solution. Use a service shared by both the tab and the parent.

in your service you can use Promises to let tabs know when the data is available:

```
    import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

    @Injectable()

    export class Service{
        constructor(){}
    }

    getParams() {    
     asyncMethod().then( (data) => { 
       this.params= data; 
       Promise.resolve(params) });
     }
    }
```

Then in your parent and pages you can get the params when they are available:

```
    this.service.getParams().then( (params) => { 

     // do whatever with the params    
});
```

Comment: Same thing... as the parent and the first tab are created at the same time, when the parent gets the info from the async method the child hasn't the data.
The solution would be to put this async method in the first tab and then use that service to pass the data through the other tabs.

Comment: there is a difference between "never", which is your original problem and "when the parent gets the info". There's no need to move the async method to the tab, leave it in the parent and use the service for everybody, look at my edit

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for asyn call from parent tab;

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  displayTab:boolean=false;
  constructor(params: NavParams) {

      this.params = params;
      console.log(this.params); // returns NavParams {data: Object}
      this.fooId = this.params.data;

      // this tells the tabs component which Pages should be each tab's root Page
      this.tab1Root = Tab1;
      this.tab2Root = Tab2;
      this.tab3Root = Tab3;

      this.asyncFunction();
    }

asyncFunction(){
    //does async func
    displayTab=true;
   }
}

<ion-tabs *ngIf="displayTab">
    <ion-tab tabTitle="Tab1" [root]="tab1Root" [rootParams]="fooId"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabTitle="Tab2" [root]="tab2Root" [rootParams]="fooId"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabTitle="Tab3" [root]="tab3Root" [rootParams]="fooId"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

This worked for me.