# Ionic 2 update [rootParams] Tabs

Tags: tabs, ionic2, nav

This is closely related to the SO question [Ionic 2 passing tabs NavParams to tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162308/ionic-2-passing-tabs-navparams-to-tab)

I have tabs view template setup as:

```
 <ion-tabs #myTabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home"  tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="My Alerts" [rootParams]="paramsData" tabIcon="warning"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Settings" [rootParams]="paramsData" tabIcon="cog"></ion-tab>
....
```

and in the constructor of the class (**main Tabs page**) I am setting **rootParams**.

```
this.paramsData = {
    settings: this.userSettings,
    facilities: this.facilities,              
 };
```

This works fine when I get the value in the **ionViewDidEnter()** lifecycle event on a child page within the Tab like this.

```
this.facilities = this.navParams.data.facilities;
let userSettings =  this.navParams.data.userSettings;
```

When I update **rootParams** in the **main Tabs page** by listening on an event like below,

```
listenToSaveEvents(){
    this.events.subscribe('save-settings', (userSettings) => {
      this.userSettings = userSettings;
      this.paramsData = {
        settings: this.userSettings,
        facilities: this.facilities            
      };    
    });
```

The child page still loads stale data.

This event is firing and the data is updating. When the ionViewDidEnter() of that child page gets fired again, it still loads the old data from navParams.

**A bit more on this.**

The reason why I am doing it this way i multiple pages share the data. But they all need consistent data and only one view updates it. On first load, the main Tabs page may already have existing data which it gets from another service.

**UPDATE ON THIS**

While I still want a solution to this, I went with [the answer in the link above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35176544/1497565).

So I ended up creating a Service like below.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

 @Injectable()
 export class ParamService {

  public paramsData: any;

  constructor(){
    this.paramsData = {};
  }
}
```

Obviously, added to the array of providers in the AppModule class. And then using it similarly to how I did with NavParams, except injecting ParamService.

```
this.facilities = this.paramService.paramsData.facilities;
this.userSettings =  this.paramService.paramsData.userSettings;
```

This can still be improved by specifying an interface instead of type *any* for paramsData as there can be different sets of parameters to pass to other pages/components.

Comment: Since the information would be shared by a few components and also that the information is going to be updated, I'll recommend a different approach, maybe using a shared service to store the data... but I don't know if that's a valid option for your project...

Comment: That's valid and that's what I ended up doing.

Comment: Would you mind add that as an answer, so other SO users facing the same issue can know how to fix it?

Comment: The answer is the same as the Params Service answer in the link above. I will edit my question to say that. I don't want to get points for someone else's work.

Comment: I tried answering this question here, kindly have a check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162308/ionic-2-passing-tabs-navparams-to-tab/44362454#44362454