# how to navigate to specific tabs index from other page(dont have tab originally) in ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a page name EatPage that doesn't have any tabs on it. What I want to do is to navigate from MyPage to tab bar index 2 and pass parameter from EatPage.

I have tried using this code to pass parameter

```
opentab2(id: string) {
    this.navCtrl.push('TabsPage', {
      docId: id
});
```

but don't know how to change tab from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Ionic Tabs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/), it is easy.

You are passing `docId` to your TabsPage. In TabsPage during the init phase, you just need to select the tab, like this:

html:

```
<ion-tabs #myTabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

ts:

```
export class TabsPage {

@ViewChild('myTabs') tabRef: Tabs;

ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.tabRef.select(docId);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Ionic Tabs, then syntax is like this.

**TabsPage**

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  fooId:any;
  constructor() {

      this.fooId = "some-value";

      // this tells the tabs component which Pages should be each tab's root Page
      this.tab1Root = Tab1;
      this.tab2Root = Tab2;
      this.tab3Root = Tab3;
    }
}
```

**Page**

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab tabTitle="Tab1" [root]="tab1Root" [rootParams]="fooId"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabTitle="Tab2" [root]="tab2Root" [rootParams]="fooId"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabTitle="Tab3" [root]="tab3Root" [rootParams]="fooId"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

else if you want to pass values i would suggest to use services.
Tell me if you want to know how its done via services.ill share the code here.

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162308/ionic-2-passing-tabs-navparams-to-tab)  and [official docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tab/)

Comment: [read this](https://blog.ionicframework.com/working-with-data-services-vs-nav-params) nice explanation for both the things.