# How to send parameters to a tab in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

im building a application in ionic 3 witch i wont to send data to a tab

i'm following this documentation:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/

this is an example of what a want:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
this.tabRef.select(2, {one, "1"});
}
```

thanks

Comment: i think here is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162308/ionic-2-passing-tabs-navparams-to-tab

Comment: thank, found a solution in this response https://stackoverflow.com/a/48608588/10806758